# Spring mvc submit form error 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Hi this is my first time to post my question on stackoverflow 
I'm a newbie starting to develop my first spring mvc app when i encounter this error submitted form request return 404 i can't figure out what i'm doing wrong can anyone please help me.

Here's my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Configuration locations must consist of one or more comma- or space-delimited
        fully-qualified @Configuration classes. Fully-qualified packages may also be
        specified for component-scanning -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>app.controller.*</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <display-name>MyBlogSite</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myblogsite</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myblogsite</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/myblogsite-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/pages/404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

My servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="app.controller" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!-- error message properties bean -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"
          id="messageSource">
            <property name="basename" value="messages"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

My controller

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package app.controller;

import dao.BlogDAO;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import models.Blog;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

/**
 *
 *
 */
@Controller
public class BlogController {

    @RequestMapping( value="blog", method = RequestMethod.POST )
    public String blog(){
        return "blog";
    }

    @RequestMapping( value="/new", method = RequestMethod.POST )
    public String newblog( @Valid Blog blog, 
                        BindingResult result,
                         ModelMap model ){

        /* 
         * initialize blogdao
         */
        BlogDAO blogDAO = new BlogDAO();

        if( result.hasErrors() ){
            return "blog";
        }

        if( blogDAO.saveAndUpdate( blog ) ){
            model.addAttribute( "status" , true );
            model.addAttribute( "message" , "Successfully save blog." );
        }else{
            model.addAttribute( "status" , false );
            model.addAttribute( "message" , "Error saving new blog." );
        }
        return "blog";
    }
}
```

My jsp page

```
<!-- header -->
<%@include file="/admin/header.jsp" %>
<!-- end of header -->

 <!-- tinymce -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../tinymce/plugins/save/plugin.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "#newBlog"
     });
</script>
<br/>
 <div class="jumbotron">
     <div class="container" style=" height:100px">
        <img src="../images/download.jpg"/>
    </div>
 </div>
<br/>
<form:form action="new" method="post" modelAttribute="blog" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-9">
           <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h3 class="panel-title">
                      <b>New Blog</b>
                  </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <br/>
                       <c:if test="${status == true}">
                          <div class="alert alert-success">
                            ${message}
                          </div>
                       </c:if>
                       <c:if test="${status == false}">
                          <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            ${message}
                          </div>
                       </c:if>
                    <br/>
                        <strong>Subject:</strong>
                        <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" 
                               class="form-control" value="${subject}"/>
                        <form:errors path="subject" cssClass="error" />
                    <br/>
                    <textarea cols="97" rows="20" id="newBlog" name="description">
                        ${description}
                    </textarea>
                    <!-- modal -->
                    <div align="left">
                        <br/>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                            </div>
                             <div class="col-sm-5">
                                 <button id="saveblog" 
                                         class="btn btn-primary"
                                         data-target="#modalsubject">Save Blog</button>
                                 <a href="index.jsp" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
              <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                  Panel content
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form:form>

<!-- footer -->
<%@include file="/admin/footer.jsp" %>
<!-- end of footer -->
```

Comment: is your app deployed properly ? what URL you are making GET request at ?

Comment: after submitting the form I get the url map to the controller but the page view return 404

Comment: post the log, view resolver should dump some log about not finding view

Comment: there no logs regarding the the 404 error status im using tomcat as application server

Answer (score 0):

change ur URL pattern to * (remove /)

it becomes

```
    <servlet-name>myblogsite</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
```

### i think it helps U

check names of beans xml match with Contextconfiglocation value

where is your myblogsite-servlet.xml make sure it exists, 
 what is servlet.xml? did you configure them in web.xml

Comment: <context-param>
        <param-name>contextconfiglocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/myblogsite-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

Comment: yup yup i configure in on my web.xml

Answer (score 0):

Your view resolver is not configured properly.Check where your jsp is present. Try removing the prefix that you are using or use a proper directory structure.

Comment: Hi Sir this request is submit to my admin folder jsp I have two functionality admin and client all client jsp are in the root location and my admin jsp are on my admin folder

Comment: I can't proceed with this bug issue but all my root jsp when a submit them they all map to there specific resourcemapping controller

Comment: see if you have different folder for your jsp's then please specify it in your controller only...Eg for admin the return should be admin/blog and for client if you have a folder named client then it should be client/blog...

Comment: Uhm but i already use netbeans debug and its doesnt seem to stop on the break point i have set

Comment: On the controller side

Comment: Please research some more on Spring and you will be able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I just solve my problem regarding the submited form and return status 404 by just editing and action attribute on the form.

I add this form action="../admin/blog" method="post" ...... 
the in my controller on the request mapping  value "admin/blog"

It didn't seem to me at first time but this is how i resolve the issue.
thank you to all responded back to my question thanks